# How can i implement advanced search in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can i implement advanced search like the one below in Django?

[image]

[Link](https://www.britishlichensociety.org.uk/resources/lichen-taxon-database)

When I searched, I don't want the page to be refresh.
What is the best practice for doing that? Ajax, rest framework, or other things...?
Is there a reference?

Comment: I’m voting Question is very general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very vague, so here is an overview of the main steps:

- On the frontend, have a form with all the desired filters
- On filter update or on form submit, send a `GET` request to the Django server with all of your parameters encoded in the URL (like a typical GET request)

Then, on the server-side (ie Django), assuming you are using Django Rest Framework:

- Create a view/action (through an API View or a Viewset) for your filter research
- Extract the filters sent by the frontend which will be located in `request.query_params`
- Perform a request in your database based on those filters:

  - You know what filters are expected
  - For each one, if it is not empty, perform an additional `filter` on your model (`Model.objects.filter(X=Y)`)
  - Then eventually return the results

There are many ways of doing filtering of a model in Django and DRF:

- You can use `Q` to perform complex queries
- You can use the `django-filters` package to easily add filtering in your viewset based on the received GET parameters